# Can someone explain this constant current load circuit?

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, constant-current, load, electronic-load

I'm currently a rising junior in EE and I was just wondering if anyone could help explain this circuit for me. The purpose for this is because I need to learn how to build a discharger (constant current load PCB) for my school's solar racing club. I have little to no concept of upper-level circuit knowledge, I just know the basics of circuit analysis i.e. not how transistors really work, advanced calculations beyond nodal/mesh analysis. If anyone could help me understand what exactly each part of this circuit does and how I should go about building for my own project, I would really appreciate it.

[image]

The specs for the battery pack of my solar racing club are as follows: 35 modules of 12 battery cells each. The nominal voltage is 126 volts and 3.6 per module. One module's capacity is 36 amp-hours. The pack trips at a defined undervoltage point of 2.5 and overvolts at 4.2. The purpose of creating a discharger is to discover modules that are lacking in capacity and to fix them.

Thank you in advance to everyone for the help, I'm pretty new on here and just want to learn as quickly as possible.

Comment: the paragraph dealing with the battery pack is irrelevant to the question

Comment: In addition to the other people’s descriptions, you should realise that the resistor wattage needs to be adequate to dissipate the power generated by the current following through it, check it using the power formula the values you decide to use.
Remember that the higher the DAC output voltage the higher the current will be, similarly the lower the DAC output the lower the current will be flowing through the load and set resistors. Make sure your resistor wattage is at least twice the power you are trying to dissipate.

Answer (score 3):

Basically A1 drives the gate of Q1 to maintain a voltage on \$R_{set}\$ that matches the command from the DAC. by maintaining a voltage there a current though the resistor is also maintained.

\$R_{FB}\$, \$C_F\$, and \$R_{ISO}\$ are there to stop various non-ideal behaviors like oscillation and wind-up.

Comment: Additional topics to search for: op-amp, negative feedback. Also potentially useful to search on the basic theory behind current mirrors and using a transistor as a current source.

Answer (score 1):

This is closed-loop control circuit.

Think of it this way: if the load current is below the target, the voltage drop across Rset will be lower than the set point defined by the output of the DAC. In this case the voltage at the non-inverting input (+) of the op amp will be higher than the voltage on the inverting-input (-). This will cause the op amp to raise the voltage applied to the gate of the FET. When this happens the FET will have its drain-to-source resistance reduced (think of it as opening a faucet), what will cause more current to flow through the load and through Rset.  The opposite happens if the current is below the target. The net result is an equilibrium condition where the current is tightly kept close to the target current determined by the ADC voltage.

Rfb, Cf and Riso are there most likely for stability reasons, to make sure the circuit does not oscillate by itself. It's possible you don't need them with a purely resistive load like you have.

Answer (score 0):

Amplifier A1 is setup as a non-inverting buffer.

The voltage at (+) is just some voltage controlled by the DAC, say 1.0V.

Since the opamp has negative feedback we can expect the voltage at (+) to be equal to the voltage at (-), as an ideal opamp would behave.

So what happens is there is a voltage of 1.0V at +.  The opamp will drive it's output until the voltage at (-) is 1.0V.
From there you can use circuit analysis.
At DC, CF is infinite impedance and is ignored.
So Cf is inf impedance, and the opamp (-) input is also inf impedance (draws no current, ideal opamp). 
This means there is no voltage drop across RFB as there is no current.  As another poster pointed out, RFB is there for other reasons that my simple DC explanation does not require.

So with no current across RFB there is no voltage drop acoss RFB and as such the voltage across Rset is 1.0V, which means the current through RSet is 1.0V / 5.1 or approx 200mA. 
Again, no current goes through RFB. So that 200mA must be going through the mosfet source to drain.   We know that none goes through to the gate (and thus no current directly from the opamp) because we are assuming this to be an ideal mosfet with no gate leakage.  A real world device will leak a little bit, or a BJT will have current in the base, depending on it's gain. This would result, for example, in only 199.99mA (10uA leaky real world mosfet) or maybe 198mA (BJT with gain = 100).
So this 200mA must be going through mosfet D-S, which then must be going through the 25 ohm load.

Hence, we have created a 200mA load.  No matter what the voltage is at VCC, the current remains the same.

This happens at any DAC input, so long as the opamp input common mode min/max is observed, the opamp max output is not exceeded, and the supply + mosfet have high enough voltage / low enough impedance to source that amount of current.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably familiar with the voltage follower:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjp07s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

An opamp with negative feedback like this acts to equalise the potential at its two inputs, INV and NINV. In this case we set the potential at NINV to some arbitrary value (1.5V here) and the opamp adjusts its output so that INV has the same potential. If the OUT voltage is too low, the opamp compensates by raising it. If it's too high, the opamp lowers it.

One key benefit is that our "reference" source of 1.5V is isolated from the whatever is connected to OUT, because of the opamp's high input impedance. We provide a potential for the opamp to "copy" and it will be the opamp's responsibilty to do whatever it has to do at its output to maintain INV at the same potential.

We can put whatever we want in that feedback path. The opamp will always adjust OUT to keep INV at the same voltage as NINV:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvMf3p.png)</sup>

The banana can decide for itself whatever voltage it wants to "drop" across it, and the opamp will act to accomodate the banana, all the while adjusting its output so that the voltage at INV equals the voltage at NINV. If, in this example, the banana wants 2V, then the opamp raises its output to 2V + 1.5V = 3.5V, but importantly the voltage at the far side of the banana is still equal to NINV, 1.5V.

After the opamp comes a [source-follower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_drain):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGr3DH.png)</sup>

For a MOSFET with a gate threshold voltage of 2V, we can say that this MOSFET will try its best to keep Vsource always 2V lower than Vgate. It draws current through the load at its drain to do this. For example, if we put 4V at the gate, and the resistor Rs only has 1V across it, then the potential difference between the gate and source is 3V, greater than the threshold voltage of the MOSFET.

It responds by becoming more conductive, allowing more current to flow from the supply source down through the load and Rs. This increases the voltage across Rs, and the increase continues until the gate-to-source difference (Vgs) equals 2V. In this way, source potential is always a couple of volts lower than gate potential, and we have control of the voltage across Rs, by varying Vgate.

Notably, we can therefore control the current through Rs by raising or lowering the gate potential, Vgate, and since this current through Rs is the same as the current through the load, we are indirectly controlling load current too.

Now we combine the opamp voltage follower with the source follower, to obtain something similar to your original circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5nsgm.png)</sup>

In essence, we provide at NINV the voltage we wish to appear across Rs, which will also set the current through it, by Ohm's law.

Because we derive feedback from the top of Rs, the opamp does whatever it has to do to make the voltage there (which is also the voltage at INV) equal the voltage at NINV. It raises and lowers its output, which is the voltage applied to the MOSFET gate, to make it so.

When the voltage across Rs is established as equal to NINV, whatever current through Rs that was needed to achieve this is sourced via the load. Thus we have effectively, and precisely, set the load current to whatever value we choose, simply by varying the voltage at NINV.

The other components \$R_{FB}\$ and \$C_F\$ are there to help mitigate phase shifts which may occur if the load is somewhat capacitive or inductive.